# Developing Admin Tool to Relocate/Remove/Add Vue Component Content

Tags: laravel, templates, vue.js, admin

We are creating a question flow for our web app, the questions are loaded via vue router, and currently we are loading vue components. So a question is vue component for that question type with some data passed in as a prop so that they component knows what question to ask, and options to display. The questions range anywhere from being radios, checkboxes, inputs, dates, etc.

We were told we would eventually have to create an administrator panel to manage these "templates" (the vue components). So that someone who can barely turn on a computer can add questions to a questionnaire and even create their own questions!

Short of creating a text editor with predefined code snippets to change these vue components, do you folks know of any other way we can go about doing this?

Here is basically what they want: Moving components around inside another vue component, adding a component from a pool of vue components, removing components.

Any help is appreciated thanks.

Comment: Take a look at this repo : https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue. Has a bunch of great libraries that might help. Such as drag and drop etc.

Comment: Thank you, will take a look.